# Complex function f is differentiable implies |f| is harmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=f: D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is differentiable. Is function $|f|$ harmonic on $D$?

Function $f$ is said to be harmonic if $\Delta f \equiv 0.$
If $f$ is differentiable then Cauchy-Riemann equations hold.

I tried to directly compute $|f|$, but I don't think it is possible in general case. Any tips?

Comment: $\log |f|$ is harmonic wherever $f$ is non zero

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, the function $\;f(z)=z\;$ is analytic and thus (infinitely) differentiable, yet (with $\;z=x+iy\,$)

$$g(x,y)=|f(z)|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\;\;\text{ isn't harmonic since}$$

$$\begin{cases}g_x=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},&g_{xx}=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\\{}\\g_y=\frac y{\sqrt{x^2y^2}},&g_{yy}=\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\end{cases}$$

and thus

$$\nabla^2g=g_{xx}+g_{yy}=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\neq0$$